# В Wireshark отфильтровать все ошибки, алерты

Tags: wireshark

Какой фильтр в Wireshark можно применить, чтобы остались только ошибки, алерты (всех протоколов)?

Answer (score 0):

https://hackware.ru/?p=7008
по данной ссылке можешь найти большое кол-во фильтров в wireshark. Вообще в сети ты не увидишь как таковых ошибок, у тебя будут разные коды ответов, например http: ошибок в нём нет, есть кода 404, 403, 500, и в wireshark есть фильтр чтобы смотреть все http запросы с определённым кодом, если тебе нужно это, можешь увеличить область поиска добавив логическое или - `||`. `http.response.code==404` вот тебе пример фильтра.
далее смотри по статье что тебе больше нужно.